# Loading more Data on a Website Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem not necessarily related to my code, as it seems to work, but a website I am trying to scrape. It does not give me more data. What I am trying to do is click a 'Load more' button until there is no more data. There are 20000 results with 50 per load. So the button needs to be clicked 400 times. After around 100 clicks, the program clicks the button, but the website does not load any more data. My question now is: Do websites restrict how much data I can load? Is my hardware responsible for this problem, aka can my RAM maybe not handle the data? I am new to python scraping so really any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't really described what actually happens when you do that approximately 100th click. For  instance, does the browser's window just not change at all? What's on the screen after that infamous click? Is your program throwing an exception? As far as whether websites restrict how much data can be loaded, you would need an answer for your specific site. But I would think that if there is a "Load more" button being presented, you are not being restricted *yet*.

Comment: Thanks Booboo for your initial answer. Of course i can specify the problem. First of, the program does not throw an exception. The 'load more' button is clicked, then a text appears 'loading more data', after that nothing happens. The website is: https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/en/tools/product-search/discount-certificates/ . Again, any help is greatly appreciated. If my code helps i can post it as well, but it seems to work just fine for the first results

Comment: Then my guess is that the problem is on the website's end. If there is any customer support you can contact, I would try that first.

Comment: Will do, thank you Booboo

Comment: One more thing: If you are able to get all the data if you do it manually (without using selenium), then maybe they recognize that you are using automation and do limit how much data you can retrieve. But customer support should be able to answer that. I would also look into whether they have an API (e.g. a web service) for getting this data so you don't have to scrape the data.